# generating an array out of another array by using a unique key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that contains 3 products with attributes of "color" and "size" and the products are identified by a number ( ['code'] ).
My problem is that when i pull the data from the database I get this array that is in 6 pieces because "color" and "size" get stored in separate arrays.

My question is, how do I generate the data into an array of these 3 products with all their data in the same array.

```
Array(

   [0] => Array
       (
        [code] => 123
        [name] => box
        [stock] => 2.00
        [price] => 10.00
        [color] => brown
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [code] => 123
        [name] => box
        [stock] => 2.00
        [price] => 10.00
        [size] => L
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [code] => 1234
        [name] => box
        [stock] => 3.00
        [price] => 11.00
        [color] => brown
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [code] => 1234
        [name] => box
        [stock] => 3.00
        [price] => 11.00
        [size] => XL
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [code] => 12345
        [name] => box
        [stock] => 4.00
        [price] => 12.00
        [size] => XL
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [code] => 12345
        [name] => box
        [stock] => 4.00
        [price] => 12.00
        [color] => gray
    )
```

)

Expected output:

```
[0] => Array
    (
    [code] => 123
    [name] => box
    [stock] => 4.00
    [price] => 12.00
    [color] => gray
    [size] => XL
)
```

What i'm looking to do is just combine the doubled array into one. Dont want to mess with SQL anymore - it gets attribute name in one table, attribute values from another table, code,stock,price from another table, name from another table. I know something can be done with just this array even if it will be just a temporary solution.

Comment: Please add your SQL query / result gathering, since the errors root lies in your query.

Comment: I'm asking strictly how to generate the data from the given array. No SQL.

Comment: That's a short-sighted way to look at this problem.  It can probably be solved by modifying the query that is fetching the data, which would be the cleaner solution.

Comment: What is the expected output? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

assuming your array is $products

```
$merged = array();

foreach($products as $product) {
    if (!isset($sorted[$product['code']])) {
        $merged[$product['code']] = $product;
    } else {
        $merged[$product['code']] = array_merge($sorted[$product['code']], $product);
    }
}
```

Use the product code as array key and then merge the array.

Comment: This was the most helpful part. I used the first part of @Phillip Maurer s answer. Because the values were not in order I changed the ORDER BY sql clause and I got the arrays in order 123,1234,12345,123,1234,12345 combined the data with a modified version of the answer above and used your code to get the final result (array with 3 products and all data).

Answer (score 1):

**If the two rows are always direct successors**, with the first one holding the `color` field, while the latter holes the `size` field, you can make it easily by iterating over them in a `for` loop:

```
$maxCount = count($array);
for ($i = 1; $i < $maxCount; $i += 2) {
    $array[$i - 1]['size'] = $array[$i]['size'];
    unset($array[i]);
}
```

This will iterate over each second element of the array and add the `size` field to the preceding field.

If you need to have succeeding array keys afterwards you can call `$arry = array_values($array);`.

---

**In case the the associated rows might not be successors** you need to map them based on their `code` field (in case thats the primary key). You can use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) for that:

```
$desiredOutput = array_reduce($array, function($output, $element) {
    if (!array_key_exists($element['code'], $output)) {
        $output[$element['code']] = $element;
    } elseif (array_key_exists('size', $element)) {
        $output[$element['code']]['size'] = $element['size'];
    } elseif (array_key_exists('color', $element)) {
        $output[$element['code']]['color'] = $element['color'];
    }
    return $output;
}, []);
```